# php regex to extract phone numbers from filenames

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I'm trying to add filenames with phone numbers in array. 
My test files are:

```
dsfdsf543-6786sdfsdfd.jpg
543-6786sdfsdfd.jpg
435-3454
dsfdsf543-6786.jpg
123-4567
543-6786.jpg
345-3454
```

My goal is different phone numbers will have separate line of elements in array. Each element in array line will have same phone number.
For example:

```
543-6786 dsfdsf543-6786sdfsdfd.jpg 543-6786sdfsdfd.jpg dsfdsf543-6786.jpg 543-6786.jpg
435-3454
123-4567
345-3454
```

My code:

```
$directory = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$handler = opendir($directory);
while ($file = readdir($handler)) {


    if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
      $regex = "/[\D]*[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}[\D]*/";
               preg_match_all($regex, $file, $results);

   }
}
print_r ($results);
```

Result is

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 345-3454 ) )
```

why only one filename in the array?
Where is my mistake?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Not a solution but a hint. Your expression can be simplified to `~\D*\d{3}-\d{4}\D*~` - there is no need to put `\D` in a character class and `[0-9]` equals to `\d` in `PCRE`.

Comment: Try `$regex = "/(?<!\d)[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}(?!\d)/";`

Answer (score 3):

You're feeding the filenames to `preg_match_all` one at a time, and each time `$result` gets overwritten.  The thing is to push `$results[0]` onto an array each time, and then dump that array.

```
$final_results = [];
while ($file = readdir($handler)) {
    if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
        $regex = "/[\D]*[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}[\D]*/";
        if (preg_match_all($regex, $file, $results) > 0)
            $final_results[] = $results[0] ;
    }
}
print_r ($final_results);
```

Updated per comment: this version creates a key=>value array where the phone number is the key and the value is all the filenames that contain that number.

```
$final_results = [];
while ($file = readdir($handler)) {
    if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
        $regex = "/[\D]*[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}[\D]*/";
        if (preg_match_all($regex, $file, $results) > 0) {
            if empty ($final_results[$results[0]]) {
                $final_results[$results[0]] = $file ;
            } else {
                $final_results[results[0]] .= " ".$file ;
            }
        }
    }
}
print_r ($final_results);
```

Once you've got this array, it's trivially easy to flatten it to a one-dimensional array like you want.

Comment: Thank you so much! Any thoughts how to have results with same phone number in same array line?

Comment: Updated answer.  I didn't test the code but the outline is right.  If this answer works for you, be sure to check as accepted, thanks!

Comment: all look ok to me, but i get HTTP ERROR 500

Comment: Hey Juan, can you take a look why there is HTTP ERROR 500?

Comment: @Vlad Sorry, no I can't.  Maybe I'm using `empty()` on a non-object?  Perhaps `! isset()` would work better.  But `500 error` is impossibly vague.  If you want to know what the real problem is, run your code in a console and not on a remote server.  Then you can print debug information and see a stack trace when your code crashes.  Good luck!